# Threading progress bar in vb.net - thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: vb.net

Would anyone be able to help me here please.  I'm fairly new to VB.net and threading so im just trying to figure out what is happening.

When I debug this I am getting the error

> thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressBar1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

I'm a little lost as to why the error is occuring or how to fix it.  I've had to put the progress bar in a separate thread otherwise the GUI crashes

```
Private Sub InstallTheAgent_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles InstallTheAgent.Click
    MsgBox("Click OK to continue to install the Agent")
    Dim t As Thread

    t = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf WorkInstallAgent)
    t.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub WorkInstallAgent()
    ProgressBarThread()
    Dim DeviceLines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(DynPath & "\machines.txt")
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = DeviceLines.Length

    Using myReader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(DynPath & "\machines.txt")
        ProgressBarThread()
        Do While myReader.Peek() >= 0

            Dim computerName As String = myReader.ReadLine
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) = True Then
                Call CopyAgent(computerName)
                Call InstallAgent(computerName)
                Call Agent(computerName)
                Call RemoveTempSoftware(computerName)
            End If
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
        Loop
    End Using

    MsgBox("Installation of the Agent Complete")
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0


End Sub

Public Sub ProgressBar()

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf ProgressBar))
    Else
        Dim DeviceLines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(DynPath & "\machines.txt")
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0

        ProgressBar1.Maximum = DeviceLines.Length
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ProgressBarThread()
    Dim p As Thread

    p = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ProgressBar)
    p.Start()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress bar is on GUI thread. If you try to access it form other thread then this error will occur.

Try usin Background worker. Check this link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/BackgroundWorkerDemo.htm

Comment: Thanks, however I have about 15 other options in my program that are already setup for threads, therefore it isn't feasible for me to switch to background workers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your code is messy. You mix data processing and progress display in all this code.
And you call a thread(ProgressBarThread), that will call a sub that might auto invoke to do... just one operation ? so why a thread ?
And Since there's only one progress bar, you can't launch several threads AND have display for each of them.

1. Have a status object for each thread (with Min, Max, Current. properties that make use of NotifyPropertyChanged, maybe title, reference to the thead for cancellation, ...)
2. On new thread creation; you give a status object to the thread, you add this status object into an observable collection of status bound to a listbox having progressbar as item style.
3. Then you'll just have to update the status in your main process thread and it works. (no need for ProgressBar subs)

Or ... Quick-and-dirty fix: use invoke each time accessing your progressbar : Me.Invoke(sub() ProgressBar1.Minimum=12)